# Rollback the execution of a msi installer from an external C# function

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, rollback

I have a program in C# winforms which launches sequentially some installers or bundles. I want to implement a button which cancels and rollbacks the execution of the current installer (just like when the user presses cancel button) then rollbacks the execution of all previous installers.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371369(v=vs.85).aspx can't you package all the installers into your own ?

Comment: What do you mean "to package all the installers into my own"? Does it include f.ex. to use Wix Burn ?

Comment: Yep I was thinking about that kind of tools, but I don't know them well, Christopher's answer seems a good way to start ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at Windows Installer XML (WiX) Burn bootstrapper.  You can write a custom bootstrapper application that drives the UI for the installation of your bundles.  It also has patterns for putting transactions around your packages and being able to roll them back.

If you want to do what you are doing now you need to register yourself as an external UI handler for the MSI's and then use the MSI API to cancel the installation and invoke a rollback.

Comment: Thanks already for the clues. How do I cancel a running installation using the MSI API?